# How to remove entries that contain NaN from a struct array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I have a struct array `a`:

```
a(1).s1 = NaN
a(2).s1 = 2
a(3).s1 = 4
a(4).s1 = 3

a(1).s2 = 1
a(2).s2 = NaN
a(3).s2 = NaN
a(4).s2 = 5
```

Ideally, I would like to create another struct array `b` without entries where `s2` contains `NaN`. So the new array `b` would look like this:

```
b(1).s1 = NaN
b(2).s1 = 3

b(1).s2 = 1
b(2).s2 = 5
```

I need this done automatically so I can apply the script to a much larger struct array.

I've been trying to create a for loop like this:

```
i = 1;
for i = find(all(~isnan([a(1:4).s2]), 1));
    b(i).s1 = a(i).s1;
    b(i).s2 = a(i).s2;
end
```

but it keeps empty entries.

Another attempt to remove entries with `NaN`:

```
b = a;
i = 1;
for i = find(all(isnan([b(1:4).s2]), 1));
    b(i) = [];
end
```

only works for the first `NaN`. Then it loses `i` count and removes incorrect entries.

Please help me out, if anyone knows how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were really close to solving this but the for loop is a bit problematic so you should use array formula like this:

```
b = a(~isnan([a.s2]));
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: You were a second faster than me, with about the same solution. Note: you can drop the `find` and use linear indexing, which gives a shorter, even more efficient solution: `b = a(~isnan([a.s2]))`

Comment: @hbaderts You are right, it is more efficient on large structure arrays. I'll update the solution.

Comment: Ah it is amazingly simple! Many thanks, it worked for my large array as well